# How can I read text using pywinauto with classname?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, pywinauto

[image]
I'm trying to read this text using pywinauto with class name but getting error.

My code is below:
[image]

Comment: please post the code and the text you are trying read here. Do not post images

Comment: Please, don't attach your code as picture. Copy and paste it here as text.

Comment: Please add the exact error message too (as text, not picture).